# Strange tag stack on Google, re: blender.stackexchange website (suspicious bug report for admin)

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed something strange about stackexchange while doing a Google search. In one hit to stackexchange with a really odd tag stack (see screencap). Thought you'd want to know there's a bunch of completely unrelated tags there, like "travel" and "christianity". Also, I noticed that most stackexchange hits didn't seem to have that tag stack? Seemed odd, so here you are:

the search URL: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=math+language+blender+driver+expression&*

the specific link with the weird tags: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfnOL70KbSAhWD1CYKHWrfDPoQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F8135%2Fusing-a-scripted-expression-driver-to-combine-two-angles&usg=AFQjCNH8ZOT_dyP5s05x56KPz-00OoCyfA&sig2=sSzDT-QE_O8xm40mjOecsA[image]

Comment: I don't see anything strange or suspicious there (besides I didn't get that result with your query); travel and christianity (along with English Language Learners and Japanese) were parts of domain names [travel.stackexchange](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) and [christianity.stackexchange](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) respectively which were lucky enough to be caught into the results by search engine.

Comment: Where's the bug? Can you clarify what you believe is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, but google turning up exactly what you searched for.
You searched for "*math language blender driver expression*" and "language" happens to be in the footer of every page.

[image: BSE footer]

So right there you hit *blender* and *language* (on every page). Then that page you linked to takes care of the "driver" and "expression" thus google in all of its wisdom is left to show the footer and how it matches your query.